# Java : Get emails which are for a given time-frame, make the query in that format

Tags: java, email

I am working on a Java application in which I want to get emails for a given time frame. Problem is, I found a way to search for emails for a given time frame after retrieving them, but not while requesting mails from the server. Any idea how it's possible?

Code for getting email :

```
Properties prop = System.getProperties();
prop.getProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "myGmailId@gmail.com", "mypassword");
inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
```

Code for searching emails for a given time :

```
SearchTerm olderThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, someFutureDate);
SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, somePastDate);
SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(olderThan, newerThan);
inbox.search(andTerm);
```